# jquery Function to return object

Tags: jquery

I have this function that is supposed to return an object when it finds it but it's not doing that.
What am i doing wrong?

```
var getEl = function(title){
    var theInputs = $('input[type=text], input[type=radio], input[type=checkbox], select, textarea')
    theInputs.each(function(){
        if (this.title==title){
            getEl = this
            console.log('found it!')
        }
    })
}

console.log(getEl('Office Status'))
```

I know that it works since found it is output on the console, but console reports undefined as the output of this line:

```
console.log(getEl('Office Status'))
```

Comment: Where is the `return` statement?

Comment: Have you possibly developed in vbscript at some point?  I think I've seen the pattern of returning a value by assigning it to the name of the function there before.

Comment: why not just use the filter function?

Comment: I had it originally with return but it did not work.

Comment: I've never done vbscript, i saw that pattern somewhere and it stuck in my head. Is that not good practice?

Answer (score 2):

```
var getEl = function(title){
    var result;
    var theInputs = $('input[type=text], input[type=radio], input[type=checkbox], select, textarea')

    theInputs.each(function(){
        if (this.title==title){
            result = this
            console.log('found it!')
            return false; // break the loop
        }
    });

    return result;
}
```

Overwriting the value of the functions variable will not work.  You want to instead return the result.

**EDIT:**

That being said, you should be able to actually replace the whole thing with this:

```
var $result = $(":input[title='" + title + "']");

if(result.length > 0) return $result[0];
```

Though it'll need some modification if you do need to specifically only get those 3 types of inputs instead of just any input.  Something like this (using your existing `theInputs` variable):

```
var $result = theInputs.filter("[title='" + title + "']");
```

Comment: Was waiting so long for you to un-delete your post. +1

Comment: @Vega Strange, I undeleted as soon as I edited.  Guess there's some lag.

Answer (score 1):

You need to return element from your function

```
var getEl = function(title){
    var el;
    var theInputs = $('input[type=text], input[type=radio], input[type=checkbox], select, textarea')
    theInputs.each(function(){
        if (this.title == title){
            el = this;
            return false;
        }
    })
   return el;
}
```

Comment: Remove the `console.log` after the `return` statement please.

Comment: Returning non-false within `each` is the same as "continue" in a standard loop.  This wont' work.

Comment: You still haven't returned any value from the function.

Comment: @JamesMontagne .. returned if title is found.. did you mean anything else.

Comment: Your function has no return.  Both of your return statements are within the `each`.  Returning `true` will continue the loop, returning `false` will exit the loop.  Neither will return a value from the overall function.